# Java: Printing MS Access database using Desktop.print

Tags: java, ms-access, printing, awt

I am trying to print my MS Access database using Desktop API. Here is my code

```
public void PrintAll() {
        JFileChooser chooseFile = new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(chooseFile);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            fileName = chooseFile.getSelectedFile();
        }

        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            desktop.print(fileName);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(chooseFile, "Error printing a database file. Access denied!");
            Logger.getLogger(SavePrint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
May 01, 2013 12:53:46 PM Model.SavePrint PrintAll
SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Failed to print file:/C:/Users/Nikki1993/Desktop/Cars.mdb. Error message: Access is denied.

    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.ShellExecute(WDesktopPeer.java:77)
    at sun.awt.windows.WDesktopPeer.print(WDesktopPeer.java:62)
    at java.awt.Desktop.print(Desktop.java:336)
    at Model.SavePrint.PrintAll(SavePrint.java:60)
    at View.V_main.print_database_buttonActionPerformed(V_main.java:222)
    at View.V_main.access$500(V_main.java:15)
    at View.V_main$7.actionPerformed(V_main.java:146)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

But I cannot print my .mdb file cause it gives me Access denied exception while I still can print MS Word, Excel and Power Point and any other format. What could be the issue with it and how can I resolve it?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the file naming. I've updated the post with the stacktrace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ACE/Jet (Access) database files are not "documents" like those produced by Word and Excel, and hence cannot be printed directly. Notice that if you right-click a Word or Excel document icon you see "Print" as an option, but if you right-click an .mdb or .accdb file you don't.

Also, if you drag an .accdb file and drop it onto a printer shortcut you'll receive an error message like this

[image: noPrint.png]

### Edit

While the database *file* cannot be printed directly, any program that can manipulate COM objects can print database *objects* if Access is installed on that machine. For example, the following Excel VBA code will open an Access database and print one of the reports in it:

```
Sub PrintAccessReport()
Dim accApp As Object  '' Access.Application
Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")  '' New Access.Application
accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb"
accApp.DoCmd.OpenReport "UserReport"  '' default action for Reports is "Print"
accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
accApp.Quit
Set accApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This explains a lot, however what would be my approach then to print an mdb file? Or there is no method to print it from file and I should use SQL queries to get information from the db and then send information to the printer?